# Specify Range of Numbers Javascript in Conditional Statement

Tags: javascript

I am sort of new to Javascript Code and I'm wondering how can I specify that x in this case can be a number in between 750 to 850.

```
 else if(DATA == "PULSOUT 12, x") {
```

*Note DATA is a user input that was taken from a textarea if that info is needed.

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking, but I think you'd have to take apart the string and examine the value with explicit code.

Comment: something like `var n = parseInt((DATA.match(/PULSOUT 12, (\d+)/)||[])[1]);
    if(n >= 750 && n < 850) {
        // OK
    }`

Comment: _"in this case can be a number in between 750 to 850"_ What do you mean by "in between"?

Comment: Range 750 - 850 numbers like 751, 800, 836, etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Ahm23, Try this:

```
if (DATA.substr(0,11) == "PULSOUT 12," && parseInt(DATA.substr(11).trim()) >= 750 &&  parseInt(DATA.substr(11).trim()) <= 850) {
```

Comment: Thanks, I figured this out some time ago just forgot to close the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can define a function which checks if input is within range `751-849` where array contains elements `[750, 850]`, pass or define array containing ranges at second parameter, use logic `n > range[0] && n < range[1]`, where `n` is user input. You can use `.match()`, `RegExp` `/\d+$` to get digits before end of string, `

```js
let x = "750";

function checkX(n, range = [750, 850]) {
  return n > range[0] && n < range[1]
}

console.log(checkX(x)); // false
console.log(checkX(x = 751)); // true
console.log(checkX(x = 850)); // false

let DATA = `PULSOUT 12, ${x = 808}`;

console.log(
  checkX(x = DATA.match(/\d+$/g).pop()) 
  && DATA.replace(/\d+$/, "") === "PULSOUT 12, "
); // true
```